# Как преобразовать std::string в uint8_t*?

Tags: c++, строки, c++11

Как конвертировать `string` в `uint8_t*`, чтобы затем правильно передать значение в функцию `WriteReg`?

```
void WriteReg(uint8_t *buffer)
{
    // some code
}

int main()
{
    string str4 = "test";
    uint8_t send_buffer[20];

    // convert str4 to send_buffer ?

    WriteReg(send_buffer);
}
```

Comment: Можно и без лишнего копирования в буфер, см. ответ Abyx.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::memcpy(send_buffer, str4.data(), str4.size() + 1);
```

Если терминальный ноль не нужен, единичку можно убрать. Ещё стоит проверить, что строка влезет в буфер, на всякий случай. А если это отправка по сети, то обычно ещё размер буфера в функцию `WriteReg` передают

Answer (score 2):

Просто сделайте каст:

```
WriteReg(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&str4[0]));
```

Comment: Если не нужна совместимость с C++03, то `data()` выглядит симпатичнее, чем пара `&` и `[0]`, имхо. Можно ещё `c_str()` для всех стандартов.

Comment: Точно, ведь ещё и `const` придётся в каст добавить, но не стоит потакать желаниям ТС, надо фиксить сигнатуру `WriteReg`. А то он ещё начнёт там в строки писать и UB вызывать.